# Can I view the "Enforce Face ID or Touch ID timeout" that is set on my MDM profile on my iPhone?

Tags: iphone, mdm, configuration-profiles, face-id

I have work email on my phone thanks to some MDM profile additions.

I'm finding on my iPhone XS that FaceId forces back to Passcode on every second attempt. This frequency seems unusually high.

My question is: **Can I view the "Enforce Face ID or Touch ID timeout" that is set on my MDM profile on my iPhone?**

Comment: I have never seen the ability to *read* a configuration payload by an end user.  If you could, you'd likely need the [Apple Configurator](https://support.apple.com/guide/apple-configurator-mac/welcome/mac) to view/edit/  The link is to the online manual - I haven't found anything that allows end users to view the profile data.  You might have better luck.

Comment: Thanks @Allan - that's helpful. Would you care to expand that as an answer to close this off?

Comment: Sure.  I’ll post later